# Outlook calender view: all-day-events not fully shown

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

i'm having a layout/view problem with outlook 2016. I don't know how the upper panel is called in english, so i call it the 'top pane' (where the 'all-day-events' are shown).

If there are too much appointments in the top pane, there **should** be a triangle button allowing the user to scroll down to see all appointments. But sometimes its shown, other times not :/

[image: Outlook: Triangle-Button]

Have a look at the next screenshot. The left part shows the top pane and in the second column we can see a yellow appointment which is not fully shown - but no scrollbar to the right or a triangle-button. The right part of the screenshot shows the **same** week, but with font-size set to 7 instead of 8. We can see, that there is another appointment below which is also not fully shown (and fully invisible in the left screenshot) - but again - no scrollbars or triangle button.

[image: Outlook: calender view]

So my question... Is there a way to resize the top panel or that the scrollbar is always shown - regardless if it is necessary or not? Or are there others solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce this issue on my Outlook 2016, this should be a error in your Office(Outlook) installation.

Try repairing your Office installation and see if there is any difference: Open Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.

Besides, please install the latest updates.

Comment: I am in an corporate envirement, all clients have this problem and all clients have the latest updates installed.